# lgfortran not found

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, linker, fortran, gfortran

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 and trying to compile some code that uses gfortran. At some point Makefiles does:

```
-L. -lgfortran
```

and I get the error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran
```

although it is installed:

```
ldconfig -p  |  grep   fortran
    libgfortran.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libgfortran.so.3
```

How can I fix it?

P.S: The Makefile:

```
## FLAGS

CC:= gcc
C++:= g++
CFLAGS:= -c -O -Dintel -g 
FC:= gfortran
FFLAGS:= -c -O -cpp -g
LD:= g++
LDFLAGS:= -O


WETTER_CGAL_FLAGS:=  -g


#WETTER-Data
WETTER_cgal: weather.cpp surface_alg.h $(WETTER_CGAL_OBJECTS) WATT_interface.h data.cpp
    $(C++) $(WETTER_CGAL_FLAGS) -c weather.cpp -frounding-math
    $(C++) -c data.cpp -frounding-math 
    $(LD) $(WETTER_CGAL_OBJECTS) weather.o data.o -o WETTER_cgal -L. -lgfortran -lgmp -lCGAL -frounding-math -fp-model
```

Comment: Could you provide a minimal Makefile that produces the error? It must necessarily be its fault, since your shell environment seems fine.

Comment: done, the questions has been updated with that information

Comment: I faced same error and eventually `~$ sudo apt-get install libgfortran-*` to install all versions to cope with it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Does by any chance your `gfortran` version differ from the version of your `g++`? Or maybe it is installed in a different location?

The `-lname` option (in this case `name` is `gfortran`) instructs the linker to search for a library file called `libname.a` in the library search path. If found and no static linking is enforced by the `-[B]static` option the linker will search once again for `libname.so` and link against it instead (if found). If `libname.a` is not found an error will be given despite the presence of `libname.so`.

There should be a `libgfortran.a` somewhere in your `gfortran` installation. Search for it with `find` and provide the path to `g++` with `-L/path/to/compiler/libs`. If `g++` is the same version as your `gfortran` the path to `libgfortran.a` will already be present in the library search path (since both C/C++ and Fortran static libraries reside in the same place). It will not be present if both compilers differ in their version though.

For example on a 64-bit RedHat based system `libgfortran.a` is located in `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/<GCC version>/` while the shared `libgfortran.so.*` are located in `/usr/lib64`.

An alternative solution is to replace `-lgfortran` with `/usr/lib/libgfortran.so.3`.

The `-L.` option is rather related to `-lCGAL` than to `-lgfortran`.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue today when compiling ATLAS and was able to fix it using a symbolic link from `libgfortran.so.3` to `libgfortran.so`.

Comment: Okay, this worked for me, but why did it work? Also, would it have been possible to just create link in `ld.so.conf.d/`?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and tried the following command. The problem was solved using this:

`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3 /usr/lib/libgfortran.so`

Comment: For me that command says: `ln: /usr/lib/libgfortran.so: Operation not permitted`

Answer (score 3):

Just make sure you:

```
gcc --version
```

And

```
gfortan --version
```

Is the same.

```
/usr/bin/
```

Contains the different versions.

Eg: If `gcc--version returns 4.7.3` and `gfortran --version 4.8`, a simple hack could be to do the following.

```
sudo cp /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 /usr/bin/gcc
```

It should work.

Comment: In my system it was pointing to /etc/alternatives/gcc, I used the `alternatives --config gcc` command to select the appropriate version of gcc

Comment: You were meant to say `gfortran --version`

Comment: For me above command says: `cp: /usr/bin/gcc-11.3.0: No such file or directory`