# Code:Blocks cannot detect gfortran although installed

Tags: linux, fortran, codeblocks, gnu, gfortran

I believe my question is similar to this post: [Linux: cannot find lgfortran though gfortran is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631365/linux-cannot-find-lgfortran-though-gfortran-is-installed). 
However, since the suggested answer does not fix my problem, there seems no other choice other than asking it again, for a desperate Linux new comer like me.

Here is the problem. I installed GNU fortran compiler 4.8.4 and can find it in terminal

```
$ which gfortran-4.8 
/usr/bin/gfortran-4.8
```

and

```
$ locate gfortran
/usr/bin/gfortran-4.7
/usr/bin/gfortran-4.8
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gfortran-4.7 
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gfortran-4.8
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/libgfortran.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/libgfortran.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/libgfortran.spec
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/libgfortranbegin.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgfortran.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgfortran.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgfortran.spec
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgfortranbegin.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3.0.0
/usr/share/doc/gfortran-4.7
/usr/share/doc/gfortran-4.8
/usr/share/doc/libgfortran-4.7-dev
/usr/share/doc/libgfortran-4.8-dev
/usr/share/doc/libgfortran3
/usr/share/man/man1/gfortran-4.7.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/gfortran-4.8.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/x86_64-linux-gnu-gfortran-4.7.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/x86_64-linux-gnu-gfortran-4.8.1.gz
/var/cache/apt/archives/gfortran-4.7_4.7.3-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/gfortran-4.8_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libgfortran-4.7-dev_4.7.3-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libgfortran-4.8-dev_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libgfortran3_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04_amd64.deb
/var/lib/dpkg/info/gfortran-4.7.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/gfortran-4.7.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/gfortran-4.8.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/gfortran-4.8.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgfortran-4.7-dev:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgfortran-4.7-dev:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgfortran-4.8-dev:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgfortran-4.8-dev:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgfortran3:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgfortran3:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgfortran3:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgfortran3:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgfortran3:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgfortran3:amd64.symbols
```

So gfortran seems installed, although I don't understand why 4.7 version is still there after my removing it.

In setting Global Compiler Settings of Code:Blocks, when I choose GNU Fortran Compiler, and its Toolchain Executables, I tried the installation directory as

```
/usr 

/usr/bin
```

and

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/
```

as suggested in the previous post, Code:Blocks tell me

```
could not auto-detect installation path of "GNU Fortran Compiler".....
```

More details of compiler configuration is here in the image (Thanks to Mike's suggestion).

[image: Details of tool chain executables]

And here's the full list of compilers on my computer:

[List of Compliers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46Nd3.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you claim that your  post is no duplicate, please show how existing posts fail solving your issue

Comment: @MarioTrucco As I said, I've tried the C:B installation directory as `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/` and it didn't work.

Comment: Please add this information: the exact name of the compiler
shown in **GNU Fortran Compiler** -> **Toolchain executables** -> **Program Files** -> **C Compiler**

Comment: I'm guessing this is because your compiler is named `gfortran-4.8` and not just `gfortran`.  See if there is an option somewhere in your IDE to specify the name of the compiler executable, not just its installation path.

Comment: Thanks @casey. Adding -4.8 solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your posting shows that you have both `gfortran-4.7` and `gfortran-4.8`
installed under `/usr/bin`.

Having multiple GCC Fortran compilers (or multiple C or C++ compilers) is
perfectly valid and commonplace. Code::Blocks will allow you configure
as many Fortran compilers as you have got, provided you give them different
names. It's also fine if you just want to configure one of them as the 
"GNU Fortran Compiler" and ignore the others.

But in any case, Code::Blocks must be able to unambiguously identify the
installed compiler that you are calling "GNU Fortran Compiler". You
have specified the **Compiler's installation directory** as `/usr/bin`
and have left the **Program files** compiler name as `gfortran`.

There is no such compiler as `/usr/bin/gfortran` in your system,
and there is no program called `gfortran` anywhere in your `PATH`. You
have `/usr/bin/gfortran-4.7` and `/usr/bin/gfortran-4.8`. As you have
installed both of them, Code::Blocks assumes you want both of them. It
can't tell which one of them you want to configure as "GNU Fortran Compiler".

So:-

- Set **Compiler's installation directory** = `/usr/bin`
- In **Program files**, change all occurrences of `gfortran` to `gfortran-4.8`,
  if you want "GNU Fortran Compiler" to mean `gfortran-4.8`.
- OK out.

Comment: Thanks Mike for such a step by step instruction. Now I see the version number matters. And the Helloworld now is compiled. Thanks you a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. If you want 4.7 as well as 4.8 configured in C::B,
go to **Global compiler settings** -> **GNU Fortran Compiler** -> **Copy**. Click **Copy**, pick a nickname for 4.7 and then make the obvious 4.8 -> 4.7 changes in the new compiler's configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Default compiler name in 20.3 version was mingw32-gfortran. However, the executable name coming with installation is x86_64-w64-mingw32-gfortran. If this is written in compiler settings. It works.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ti43m.png)

Answer (score 0):

The install file `codeblocks-20.03mingw-setup` installs the file `gfortran.exe` into the `C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin` directory. However the `Settings>Compiler>toolchainexecutables autodetect` function looks for `mingw32-gfortran.exe`.

To fix this, in `toolchainexecutables`, change the filename `mingw32-gfortran.exe` to `gfortran.exe` in 3 places, then autodetect will find it.