# ld: library not found for -lgfortran - Mac Symlink issue?

Tags: symlink, gfortran, cc

I am trying to install ObsPy with pip.

The installation fails on the cc command below:

```
cc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/obspy/taup/src/emdlv.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/obspy/taup/src/libtau.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/obspy/taup/src/ttimes_subrout.o -lgfortran -o build/lib.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/obspy/lib/libtaup.so

ld: library not found for -lgfortran
```

This SO question is similar: [lgfortran not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881002/lgfortran-not-found), but the solution there was to change the makefile. I don't know how to do that when unsing pip install. I have installed gfortran using homebrew.

Is there a way that I can place a symlink to the existing gfortran lib folder in the location that this command is searching?

Would that location be `/usr/local/lib`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Heyhey,

there are some solutions. The easiest is to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to where the gfortran shared library is located.

`locate libgfortran.a`

Other then that you can also install the latest git version of ObsPy which should have solved this problem. Go to http://www.obspy.org to get the git URL.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, it took me a while to get back to this project, but this did the trick. I added LIBRARY_PATH to my bash_profile. I edited your answer because I first tried to add LD_LIBRARY_PATH, which did not work for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can also find the location of the lib using:

```
sudo find /usr -iname 'libgfortran*.a' | xargs shasum
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, what solved was setting this in the .pro file:

```
QMAKE_LIBDIR += /path/to/lib
```