# When installing cvxopt , I get an error that it cannot find -lgfortan

Tags: windows, fortran, gfortran, cvxopt

I can only find `libgfortan.a`. I am installing cvxopt using cmd and following the [instruction on the website](http://cvxopt.org/install/index.html). I get an error that it cannot find `-lgfortan`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [lgfortran not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881002/lgfortran-not-found)

Comment: that was on ubuntu, i am on windows! @Peter

Answer (score 1):

`-lgfortran` is [expanded](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Libraries_002fSearch.html) by [linker](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Specify_the_libraries_for_the_linker_to_use) to `libgfortran.a`. Your problem is that you do not probably have it on linker's search path. You could copy libgfortran.a to your src directory as you have to do for [lapack and blas](http://cvxopt.org/install/index.html)

> Copy libblas.a and liblapack.a to the src directory

or specify gfortran search path by `-L<dir>` in your link command.